# Carousel push notification in Android

Tags: android, image, android-studio, push-notification, notifications

How to build Android app which can send push notification like carousel view
like [this](https://qgraph.io/blog/rich-carousel-push-notifications-android-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

> QGraph Mobile URM (Customer User Relationship Management) platform now
>   enables app marketers to send multiple messages in a single
>   notification.
>
> Insert multiple images, each with its own deeplink, to
>
> Showcase multiple products/promotions/articles Highlight multiple
>   features Narrate a compelling story through push notifications Learn
>   more at http://qgraph.io